# Inner join on two tables, with clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
with one as
    (Select sno = ROW_NUMBER()OVER (order by complaint_id), Complaint_Id, Complaint.ComplaintType_id, Complaint.complaintProfileId, Complaint.Description, 
                                Complaint.Email, Complaint.PriorityLevel_id, Complaint.Date_Complained, Complaint.Status, Complaint.AdminComments, Complaint.Phone, Complaint.Evidence
                    from Complaints Complaint )
```

The result of this query is (not the entire result)

```
sno    complaintProfileId
1              14
2              15
3              15
4              14
5              14
6              13
```

The second subquery:

```
two as
                    (SELECT Complaint.complaintProfileId,
          CASE 
               WHEN MMB_Name IS NOT NULL THEN MMB_Name  
               WHEN UPPMembership.profile_id  IS NOT NULL THEN 'UPP'
               ELSE 'Not found'
          END as Name
      FROM Complaints Complaint
         LEFT JOIN  MMBMembership 
         ON MMBMembership.profile_id = Complaint.complaintProfileId
         left JOIN MMB_BusinessProfiles mmbProfiles
         ON mmbProfiles.MMB_id = MMBMembership.MMB_id
         LEFT JOIN UPPMembership
         ON UPPMembership.profile_id = Complaint.complaintProfileId)


complaintProfileId  Name
14                  UPP
15                Marlon
15                Marlon
14                  UPP
14                  UPP
13                 Rodolfo
```

So this is where I am having trouble with

```
select one.*, two.Name 
 from one join two
 on one.complaintProfileId = two.complaintProfileId
```

`This query returns 36 records.` id 14 is being returned 9times and 15-6times and so on..

I am doing a inner join  but still not sure

Thanks
Sun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join on a unique key.  Each '14' on the left side is being joined to each of the three '14's on the right side. (3x3=9)

Comment: You could *probably* have gotten rid of the join to Complaint in `two` there.